# How to truncate the decimal values of a floating point number without rounding?

Tags: matlab

I tried many MATLAB functions. The `round` function will convert `2.99` value to nearest integer `3`, but I need to convert `2.99` value to `2` by truncating `.99`. How to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `fix()` function:

```
>> fix(4.55)

 = 4
```

Comment: This isn't any different than Paul R's answer.

Comment: @rayryeng, let's consider ninja's answer as valid (not marking it as answer but just another answer) given he is a relatively new to the community. If you have -1'ed the post, I request you to please undo it, as this post only suggests one way whereas Paul's post suggests more than one solution.

Comment: @theghostofc - I didn't -1 the answer.  I just commented that it isn't any different from Paul's answer, who answered about 20 minutes before ninja did.  It is most certainly correct, but I didn't upvote it because it doesn't add any more information in comparison to Paul's answer.

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks for the quick update. I appreciate it, and agree with what you have said :)

Comment: @theghostofc - No problem at all.  I'm glad that you are taking charge and ensuring that new users are feeling welcome.

Comment: your suggestions are valuable and quick. i am very glad to be a part of this website.

Answer (score 8):

You can either use [**`floor`**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), which rounds towards -INF, or [**`fix`**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html), which rounds towards 0. The choice depends on how you want to handle negative values - if you're only dealing with positive values then either will give the required behaviour.

Comment: `trunc` is wrong, as it is a symbolic function, it won't work for this case and requires the Symbolic Math Toolbox. You were actually looking for `fix`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: thanks for the edits - I shouldn't try to post answers before I've had coffee!

Comment: your suggestions are valuable and quick. i am very glad to be a part of this website.

Comment: You can do even better my choosing to accept this answer.